# Bucketing results in aging buckets in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2014

This is a two part question.

First, I'm an Excel user and just gained SQL Server access in hopes of automating some of my reports. I understand how to select the columns I need, however I need to use some of these columns to create new columns based on my specifications. I am going to provide the `if` statements I currently use in my Excel version.

1st - I need a column with this...

```
=IF(O4="Opened",NETWORKDAYS(L4,$AM$4,Holidays!$A:$A),"")
```

So if `O4 = "opened"` I use the `networkdays` formula to determine how many days it's been open. Struggling to figure out how to do this in SQL Server

2nd - In another column, I need to bucket out the result of the above based on the below criteria. This is my Excel formula:

```
=IF(AF4<=6,"0-5 Days",IF(AF4<=11,"6-10 Days",
IF(AF4<=16,"11-15 Days",
IF(AF4<=21,"16-20 Days",
IF(AF4<=26,"21-25 Days",
IF(AF4<=31,"26-30 Days",
IF(AF4<=36,"31-35 Days",
IF(AF4<=41,"36-40 Days",
IF(AF4<=46,"41-45 Days",
IF(AF4<=51,"46-50 Days",
IF(AF4<=56,"51-55 Days",
IF(AF4<=61,"56-60 Days",
IF(AF4<=66,"61-65 Days",IF(AF4<=71,"66-70 Days","71+ Days"))))))))))))))
```

Struggling to figure out how to do this in SQL Server.

I would really appreciate any help you can offer. Someone sent me an example of a query they have using a "case" function but it either won't work in my situation or I am just having an issue deciphering the function.

I use SQL Server 2014

Comment: Please place your codes in correct style.

Comment: You may need to post your expected result ,we can use case functions.we can use case like ..select case when af4<=6 then "0-5 days" else null end 'af4' from your table..but need more info

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what does the first one. Dont know what is `NETWORKDAYS`

Second one you use a `CASE` expresion

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN `AF4` <= 6  THEN "0-5 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 11 THEN "6-10 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 16 THEN "11-15 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 21 THEN "16-20 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 26 THEN "21-25 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 31 THEN "26-30 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 36 THEN "31-35 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 41 THEN "36-40 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 46 THEN "41-45 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 51 THEN "46-50 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 56 THEN "51-55 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 61 THEN "56-60 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 66 THEN "61-65 Days"
          WHEN `AF4` <= 71 THEN "66-70 Days"
          ELSE "71+ Days"
      END as `AF4`
```